# all? method behavior with ampersand (&) and a block

Tags: ruby

I have a method to check if a coordinate is valid.

```
def valid_coordinate?(coordinate)
  valid_latitude?(coordinate['lat']) && valid_longitude?(coordinate['lng'])
end
```

When I try to use it with `all?` for an array of hashes (An example hash is `{"lat" => 63, "lng" => -24}`), it works with a block but it does not work with an ampersand.

Working version:

`coordinates.all? { |c| valid_coordinate?(c) }`

Non-working version:

`coordinates.all?(&:valid_coordinate?)`

I get the following error:

`` NoMethodError: undefined method `valid_coordinate?' for {"lat"=>63, "lng"=>-24}:Hash ``

I also checked the [documentation page](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html) for my Ruby version but could not find an explanation. As far as I know, an ampersand can be used with this method (`[1,3,5].all?(&:odd?)`).

Comment: `coordinates.all?(&method(:valid_coordinate?))` would work but `coordinates.all? { |c| valid_coordinate?(c) }` is shorter and easier to understand.

Comment: Alternatively you could create a `Coordinate` class with `lat` and `lng` attributes and a `valid?` method. Then you could write `coordinates.all?(&:valid?)` given that all elements are `Coordinate` instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This 'ampersand' notation is a short form of:

```
coordinates.all? { |c| c.valid_coordinate? }
```

It's obviously different from what you wanted since `valid_coordinate?` is being called on the object held by `c` variable instead of `self`:

```
coordinated.all? { |c| valid_coordinate?(c) }
```

And that's why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to what Marek said

`&` is shorthand for [to_proc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc)
`:` is just a symbol notation (Read on ruby symbols)

Now, as per the definition of to_proc the symbol is called upon the object itself.

Which means, a proc object is created and that is called on the object which we would get inside the block.

Elaborating with example.

```
irb(main):009:0> [1,2,3].map(&:fn)
Traceback (most recent call last):
        5: from /Users/manu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/bin/irb:23:in `<main>'
        4: from /Users/manu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/bin/irb:23:in `load'
        3: from /Users/manu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/irb-1.0.0/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        2: from (irb):9
        1: from (irb):9:in `map'
NoMethodError (undefined method `fn' for 1:Integer)
```

In the snippet above, Integer doesn't have `fn` method, hence it fails. 
An integer has an `odd?` method though, let's try that.

```
irb(main):011:0> [1,2,3].map(&:odd?)
=> [true, false, true]
```

In your case what is happening is that, you are trying to call your custom method on the hash object itself, which would obviously fail because hash does not have that method.

Hope this clears up.

As a side note, if you are wondering how to pass such custom methods, I wrote a bit about it [here](https://dev.to/manuraj17/functional-ruby-460d)